# Graph API Access Denied after giving all required permissions

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Graph API to consume some services (cloud meetings, OneDrive) on-behalf the users using Web API.

must services are working fine but some services are giving the error `accessDenied` even after I gave all required permissions

example: getting user's following items.

[image]

Comment: Its working for me Though i have given only two permission Files.ReadWrite.All and Sites.ReadWrite.All .

Comment: Please check the what the are permission you have assigned based on your subsscription and also check Azure AD role you have been assigned.

Comment: Please check did you given the permission to user check oneDrive data of specific user on-belahf of other user : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/remove-former-employee-step-4?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: Yes I gave the permission, and i am using over 15 end-points on-behalf of the user

Comment: Did you add both delegated and application-level permissions?

Comment: Hello @esamaldinelzain did your issue resolve?

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found that the `Graph` Explorer is not giving full access, I just skipped it and I gave all the required permissions, I tried from my `C#` code it's working fine

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
var items = await graphClient.Users["example@sample.test"].Drive.Items
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

**Update**

there are some services I added the permission from [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy)